# How to save snapshots of data with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Consider this scenario:
I have a `DbContext` with a bunch of `DbSets`. Of those, 2 are of particular interest: Employees and Shifts. At any arbitrary point in time, I want to save a 'snapshot' of these 2 `DbSets`. By snapshot I mean basically all the data that was available through those `DbSets`. Such a snapshot must then be discoverable via `DbContext` (in other words, some metadata about the snapshot (e.g. when it was taken) must be saved to the database). At a later time, I must be able to 'restore' such a snapshot, effectively restoring Employee and Shift `DbSets` to what they have been when the snapshot was taken. When a snapshot is restored, only the 2 `DbSets` of interest must be affected (i.e. Employees and Shifts), all other unrelated data must remain unchanged.

Ideally, all that would work with a single database but if easier/better/more viable to use multiple databases, that's also an option. I'm working with .Net 6, EF Core 6.0.7 and npgsql backend. I'm new to EF Core and I'm open to options. I'm aware that there isn't a special EF mechanism for that. I'm asking about how to best achieve what I need.

To give some practical context: I have an app where users, amongst other things, can view a list of employees and shifts available to these employees. Users can create/update/delete the shifts or employees. At any point in time, user can click 'Create shifts and employees backup' button. Users can later view a list of saved backups with a timestamp and choose to restore any of them.

Comment: What is the problem to create 3 new tables and save data to them? There is no special mechanism in EF Core fro that.

Comment: I'm aware there's no special mechanism in EF for that. I updated my question to make that clear. I'm asking for what my options are. You are welcome to elaborate on your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Since you are using Postgres my immediate reaction would be to take a snapshot with a big ol' JSON object. 
I would create a backup table which would have: DateTime backup was created, maybe a version number (if date isnt completely sufficient), and maybe a column of "Count Restored" which indicates the number of times this backup has been restored (just for meta knowledge). 
I would go with JSON, as Postgres allows a `jsonb` type in a table, and EF will allow that to come in as a `JsonElement` class object. 
Might be a pain to make sure your migration from JSON to SQL works

Comment: `DbContext`is NOT designed to be long running. You should instead create it, manipulate, save and dispose. Then you don't need 'snapshots'.

Comment: I would just keep the same tables and add a nullable column with DateTime. So if there is a DateTime set... that record is a backup and if not it is the current active one. You can add also some correlation ID columns if it is needed. I would not do serializations because if in the future u add new columns or remove some from current tables, you will have problems with keeping the serialized data with versions and have to know how to deserialize them